# Unsupervised classification "Error: Image.sample: Computed value is too large."

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification

I am trying to do an unsupervised classification for a small area in Barcelona. I uploaded an RGB image of 0.25cm of spatial resolution and I derived some indexes from it. Then, I added all the indexes as a band into the same image to use it as input in the unsupervised classification.

The problem is that I cannot map the results and I cannot download them, GEE reports all the time the same error: **"Error: Image.sample: Computed value is too large."**

Should I reduce my study area?

The code is as follows:

// Image from ICC, 25 cm of spatial resolution (RGB, with DN)

```
var bcn = ee.Image(image)

// Image scaled to get the correct HSV values

var img = bcn.divide(1000)

// INDEXES DERIVED FROM THE RGB (HSV, GNDVI, BNDVI, B_VNDVI, ratio_green, ratio_blue, ratio_red, textures (8 in total))    

// var HSV

var hsv = img.select(['b3','b2','b1']).rgbToHsv();
print(hsv)

var value = hsv.select("value")

var hue = hsv.select('hue')

var saturation = hsv.select('saturation')

// Var derived from NDVI

var G_NDVI = img.normalizedDifference(["b2", "b3"])
var B_NDVI = img.normalizedDifference(["b1", "b3"])
var V_BNDVI = img.normalizedDifference(["b2", "b1"])


// Ratio ________

var b3 = img.select("b3")
var b2 = img.select("b2")
var b1 = img.select("b1")

var ratio_blue = img.expression("(b1) / (b1 + b2 + b3)", {
    b3: img.select("b3"),
    b2: img.select("b2"),
    b1: img.select("b1").rename('ratio_blue')
})

var ratio_green = img.expression("(b2) / (b1 + b2 + b3)", {
    b3: img.select("b3"),
    b2: img.select("b2").rename('ratio_green'),
    b1: img.select("b1")
})

var ratio_red = img.expression("(b3) / (b1 + b2 + b3)", {
    b3: img.select("b3").rename('ratio_red'),
    b2: img.select("b2"),
    b1: img.select("b1")})


// Texturas Standard Deviation

var texture_ratio_blue = ratio_blue.reduceNeighborhood({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
 kernel: ee.Kernel.square(5),
});


var texture_G_NDVI = G_NDVI.reduceNeighborhood({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
 kernel: ee.Kernel.square(5),
});

var texture_b2 = b2.reduceNeighborhood({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
 kernel: ee.Kernel.square(5),
});

var texture_saturation = saturation.reduceNeighborhood({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
 kernel: ee.Kernel.square(5),
});

// Texturas Median

var texture_green_median = b2.reduceNeighborhood({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
 kernel: ee.Kernel.square(5),
});

var texture_saturation_median = saturation.reduceNeighborhood({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
 kernel: ee.Kernel.square(5),
});

var texture_ratio_blue_median = ratio_blue.reduceNeighborhood({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
 kernel: ee.Kernel.square(5),
});

var texture_G_NDVI_median = G_NDVI.reduceNeighborhood({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
 kernel: ee.Kernel.square(5),
});

// Composite all the bands

var composite = img.addBands(hsv).addBands(G_NDVI).addBands(B_NDVI).addBands(V_BNDVI)
.addBands(ratio_blue).addBands(ratio_red).addBands(ratio_green).addBands(texture_G_NDVI)
.addBands(texture_ratio_blue).addBands(texture_b2).addBands(texture_saturation)
.addBands(texture_G_NDVI_median).addBands(texture_ratio_blue_median)
.addBands(texture_saturation_median)
.addBands(texture_green_median)


print(composite)

// Unsupervised classification___________________

// Display the image
Map.centerObject(img)

// training region is the full image
var training = composite.sample({
  region: geometry,
  scale: 0.25,
  numPixels: 1e9
});

// train cluster on image
var clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(15).train(training);

// cluster the complete image
var result = composite.cluster(clusterer);

// Display the clusters with random colors.
Map.addLayer(result.randomVisualizer(), {}, 'clusters');


// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: result.clip(geometry),
  description: 'result',
  scale: 0.25,
  maxPixels: 2e9,
  region: geometry
});
```

Comment: You haven't included the complete script. Please provide a link to your code editor script, and share all used assets. I'm guessing that your geometry is too complex. Try to plug in geometry.bounds() whenever you use it, to verify if that's the case.

Comment: The link is as follows: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fjtbsurrey%2Fdefault%3ABCN_CLASSIFICATION1

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/44cf8c04f30c1b081d4a45927af3b293

Comment: You haven't shared your `users/jtbsurrey/BCN_ICC` asset. Go to the `Assets` tab on the left-hand-side, click `BCN_ICC`, click `Share`, check `Anyone can read` box, and finally press `Done`.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e12f4e80153b588259dda405970c085a apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

You are sampling **way** too many pixels for your training data set: `2e9`. You only have some `4e6` pixels in your composite to start with. Maybe you mixed up the `maxPixels` property, which show up here and there, with `numPixels`, which specifies the number of pixels you want to sample?

The second problem is the way you're combining the `trees`, `roads`, `urban`, and `shadows` collections. You could do something like this:

```
  function addClass(features, classValue) {
    return features.map(function (feature) { return feature.set('class', classValue) })
  }

  var training_data = addClass(trees, 0)
    .merge(addClass(urban, 1))
    .merge(addClass(road, 2))
    .merge(addClass(shadows, 3))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/af288a0663f06a35b15693630462693e